# Shell Script mktemp, what's the best method to create temporary named pipe?

Tags: linux, shell, security, pipe

I'm aware its best to create temporary files with `mktemp`, but what about named pipes?

I prefer things to be as POSIX compliant as possible, but Linux only is acceptable.  Avoiding Bashisms is my only hard criteria, as I write in `dash`.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

```
tmppipe=$(mktemp -u)
mkfifo -m 600 "$tmppipe"
```

Unlike regular file creation, which is prone to being hijacked by an existing file or a symbolic link, the creation of a name pipe through [`mkfifo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/mkfifo.html) or the [underlying function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mkfifo.html) either creates a new file in the specified place or fails. Something like `: >foo` is unsafe because if the attacker can predict the output of `mktemp` then the attacker can create the target file for himself. But `mkfifo foo` would fail in such a scenario.

If you need full POSIX portability, `mkfifo -m 600 /tmp/myfifo` is safe against hijacking but prone to a denial of service; without access to a strong random file name generator, you would need to manage retry attempts.

If you don't care for the subtle security problems around temporary files, you can follow a simple rule: create a private directory, and keep everything in there.

```
tmpdir=
cleanup () {
  trap - EXIT
  if [ -n "$tmpdir" ] ; then rm -rf "$tmpdir"; fi
  if [ -n "$1" ]; then trap - $1; kill -$1 $$; fi
}
tmpdir=$(mktemp -d)
trap 'cleanup' EXIT
trap 'cleanup HUP' HUP
trap 'cleanup TERM' TERM
trap 'cleanup INT' INT
mkfifo "$tmpdir/pipe"
```

Comment: I actually already chose this as my solution earlier yesterday, I was waiting to see if someone posted it, or a better one.  I also felt the dir was the way to go, in my case. Regardless... Thanks for the help, I appreciate it.

Comment: Shouldn't the trap command be `trap "rm -rf '$tempdir'" EXIT HUP INT TERM`? Can trap do it's own variable expansion?

Comment: @Six Your command would expand `$tempdir` at the time the `trap` command is evaluated, not at the time the trap is triggered. In this case, it doesn't make any difference, except that your code breaks horribly if the value of `tempdir` contains a single quote, whereas my code always works.

Comment: @Gilles That's a nice feature. I had tried your single quote example without luck, so I thought trap was unable to evaluate variables at runtime. It turned out that my `$tempdir` was declared locally and it must be defined globally for trap to have access to it. Makes sense now...

Comment: @Gilles ... as long as `$tempdir` *value* does not change either, which is acceptable for basically all purposes. Just be careful not to use the same name to create multiple temp files/dirs...

Comment: @gilles Why do you trap `INT HUP TERM`? Doesn't `EXIT` cover all of those?

Comment: @Sukima Unfortunately, no, it depends on the shell.

Comment: Would `readonly tmpdir=$(mktemp -d)` protect against the problem MestreLion mentioned, namely that tmpdir might be accidentally redefined later in the script?

Comment: @RobinA.Meade Yes, if the shell has `readonly`. But if that's an issue, you have bigger problems. If your script is so complex that you can't keep track of all the variables that it uses, you should probably use a different language.

Answer (score 8):

A safer alternative is to use `mktemp` to create a directory safely, then put your named pipe inside that directory, do an `rm -R $dir` to get rid of it in the end.

Comment: I opted to create the FIFO in a `mktemp` directory, as it was the really the only acceptable answer,  Just in case you didn't notice, @Gilles already posted this answer in-depth.

Answer (score 2):

Use the "dry-run" option:

```
mkfifo $(mktemp -ut pipe.XXX)
```

Comment: According to the man pages, the use of the `-u` option "is not encouraged".

Comment: @dogbane So is the use of `-t`, but as long as it works reliably, I'd go with it.

Comment: sorry, where does it say that `-t` is discouraged?

Comment: @dogbane If it is in any way critical, I'd make a tiny C application, calling the `mkstemp()` function (http://linux.die.net/man/3/mkstemp). The `-t` switch isn't discouraged, it is `-p`, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mktemp` to create a temporary file, then delete it and create a named pipe with the same name.

For example:

```
TMPPIPE=$(mktemp -t pipe.XXX) && {
    rm -f $TMPPIPE
    mkfifo $TMPPIPE
}
```

Comment: Does deleting the `$TMPPIPE` before the `mkfifo` avoid the 'unsafe' problem associated from doing `TMPPIPE=\`mktemp -u\` ; mkfifo $TMPPIPE` ?

Comment: @TechZilla `mkfifo` is actually safe, unlike usual regular file creation from the shell. If it wasn't, creating a file then deleting it would not help at all (in fact it would greatly facilitate the attacker's job by not requiring him to guess the file name). So dogbane's answer works, but the intermediate file creation is a useless complication.

Comment: @Gilles, Do you know in what regard the `mktemp` man page called the `-u` option 'unsafe'?

Comment: @dogbane, I voted up on your answer, and your comments which I felt were solid.  Although, I already completed this yesterday.. I was just waiting to see when someone posted either my solution, or hopefully a better one.  So even though I used `mktemp -d` you still got some points for your input.  Thank you for all your help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: @TechZilla `mktemp -u` is unsafe when creating a regular file, because it provides the protection against denial of service (if the name it generates is sufficiently unpredictable) but does not prevent an attacker from creating the file under the program's nose. Creating a fifo instead of a regular file is a rare use case that the man page doesn't address.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mkfifo` or `mknod` in Unix, where by two separate processes can access the pipe by name — one process can open it as a reader, and the other as a writer.

```
mkfifo my_pipe
gzip -9 -c < my_pipe > out.gz
cat file > my_pipe
```

The named pipe can be deleted just like any file:

```
rm my_pipe

mkfifo --mode=0666 /tmp/namedPipe
gzip --stdout -d file.gz > /tmp/namedPipe
```

NamedPipe can be used a regular file for only reading once.

http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2156

Comment: I'm fully aware about named pipes, and `mkfifo`.
It doesn't address my question about *temporary* named pipes, anymore than `mkdir` would address creating temporary directories.

Comment: How does this address the issues that `mktemp` addresses to *safely* create a named pipe?

Comment: oh ok, best is to create them under /tmp, they are temporary files by definition and will clear off once the system reboots. Or better yet, have a shell function which will create the namedpipe out of the `mktemp` result itself (ofcourse by deleting the temp file first and then running `mkfifo` on the same).  `mktemp` can also be used to create a temporary directory, try with `-t -d` switch.