# Is the data transiting through a pipe confidential?

Tags: security, pipe

I read the following question ([Shell Script mktemp, what's the best method to create temporary named pipe?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29851/shell-script-mktemp-whats-the-best-method-to-create-temporary-named-pipe)) but I'm wondering whether it is preferable to use a temporary named pipe to transfer sensitive data between programs as opposed to an unnamed/anonymous shell pipe?

Specifically I'm interested in whether this type of approach (from http://blog.kdecherf.com/2012/11/06/mount-a-luks-partition-with-a-password-protected-gpg-encrypted-key-using-systemd/) is safe:

```
# Open the encrypted block device
gpg --batch --decrypt $key_file 2>/dev/null | sudo $CRYPTSETUP -d - luksOpen $mount_device $key >& /dev/null || exit 3
```

In which cases could the Luks Keyfile be hijacked?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The command line you are suggesting is secure.

All other things being equal, "normal" anonymous pipes (created with the `pipe(2)` system call or the shell's familiar `|` syntax) are always going to be more secure than named pipes because there are fewer ways for something else outside the system to get ahold of either one of the ends of the pipe. For normal anonymous pipes, you can only read or write from the pipe if you already have in your possession a file descriptor for it, which means you must either be the process that created the pipe, or must have inherited it (directly or indirectly) from that process, or some process that had the file descriptor deliberately sent it to you through a socket. For named pipes, you can obtain a file descriptor to the pipe if you don't have one already by opening it by name.

On operating systems like Linux that have `/proc` there is always the possibility that another process can peek into `/proc/pid/fd` an access file descriptors belonging to a different process, but this is nothing unique to pipes (of whatever kind), and for that matter they can peek into another process' memory space too. The "peeker" must be either running under the same user as the subject or root, so it's not a security problem.

Comment: Sorry to raise the dead, but why is it secure? Does this boil down to security via obscurity? The return value from pipe(2) is two ints. Suppose I write a program to continually try to open random integers. Maybe taking advantage of some pattern in their creation. Isn't it feasible I could eventually open an FD that didn't "belong" to me?

Comment: @JeffreyBlattman You can't ever "accidentally" use an FD that doesn't "belong" to you, in the sense that you mean. If you aren't the process that opened the pipe and you didn't receive a file descriptor for the pipe through any other means (as described in my answer), then there is no file descriptor of yours that designates that pipe. Think of a file descriptor as a pointer to the the in-kernel object that represents the pipe. If the kernel has never at any point given you a pointer to the object in question, you can't point to it. It's not security by obscurity.

Comment: Thank you for for your explanation so far. "If the kernel has never at any point given you a pointer to the object in question, you can't point to it"- Why? Does the kernel protect it via process ID (I don't think so). What's the difference between it being sent over a socket (or any other xfer method), and another process "guessing" it? What's special about it going through a socket that makes it usable by the other process? What prevents a process from using it if it "guesses" the value of the FD?

Comment: Maybe the confusion is around getting a handle to the FD. You seem to be saying process B couldn't use it because it can never obtain the "object" that represents it. Is an FD not just an integer that can be fed into `fdopen(3)`? If I had two terminals on a computer, and on terminal A I ran a process that printed out an FD value of 100, then I called over to my buddy on terminal B, told him the value of 100, and he fed it into his program that did an `fdopen(100, ...)`, would that work or not?

Comment: @JeffreyBlattman Your scenario with FD 100 won't work. terminal A and terminal B are (presumably!) running completely separate shells in different processes. Just because terminal A's shell process has an FD #100, it doesn't mean that terminal B's shell process has one too — or if it does have an FD #100, that it designates the same file.

Comment: @JeffreyBlattman transmitting a file descriptor over a socket works because the kernel gets involved. It's done with a special system call (`sendmsg` with ancillary data attached) which requests that the kernel take a file (designated by a file descriptor because that's how you designate files) and make it available to whichever process reads it out of the socket at the other end. From the receiver's perspective, it's only because the kernel agrees to give you a file descriptor corresponding to that file that you can get one. Otherwise, you "don't have a pointer".

Comment: Okay I get it. FDs are per-process. You can't just send one it to another process. You have to involve the kernel as an intermediary to "tunnel" the data. The kernel creates the conduit. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

No. Pipes on Linux are interceptable through `/proc/$pid/fd/$thePipeFd` as if they were unlinked fifos created by the pipe creator and (I guess with their umask applied?).

If started from a nonroot shell, one could look up the fd of the reading end of the pipeline and get the data, then rewrite the data again to hide the snooping.

Processes still have an expectation of privacy (unless you have allowed ptrace attachments from nonrelated processes via `/proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope`) from same-uid processes if they don't use the filesystem for private data.

Unfortunately, pipes on Linux seem to be equivalent to using the filesystem with unlinked files.

I believe `socketpair` should be a safer alternative to `pipe()`.
While also exposed through `/proc/$pid/fd/$sockeFd`, accessing `/proc/$pid/fd/` files works by `open`ing them, but sockets aren't `open`nable and (connecting through a recreated unlinked named unix socket won't give you a connection to the binder of the unlinked socket).

(For extra tight security, communication through `socketpair` between a parent and a child should be further reinforcable via pids sent as ancillary credentials along with the messages, but that shouldn't be necessary, IMO.).

Alternatively shared anonymous memory should work too, but that doesn't map (pun intended) nicely to the shell (you can create a binary to allow you to do `./socketline 'command0 ...' \| 'command1 ...' \| 'command 2...'`).